# How to kill child of target process in Windows

Tags: bash, process, kill

I have multiple processes with the same name.However there are some that have child processes.I want to kill all those children.How can i manage that considering i know only the name of the group of processes and not the specific PID:

[image: Picture]


In the picture above i have two processes with the same name , however i want to kill the **child** of the one that has it.How can i manage that ?

**P.S** The environment is Windows, but i am running with git for windows.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows that the child is a service.

You can therefor stop the service itself to kill the process.

Commandline would be `net stop Fabric` but git might have its own method of interacting with services.